# Setting Left and Right cell borders at the same time in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, border

Wondering if there's a way to set both the left and right borders of a cell with a single statement?  Something akin to the way `msgBox` configurations can be combined/added together (e.g. `vbYesNo + vbQuestion`).  I tried:

```
Cells(j, i).Borders(xlEdgeLeft + xlEdgeRight)
```

Which leads to an error for me.  It's a bit duplicative to code each border individually...

Here what I've come up with:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    For j = 2 To 6 + numAcft
        Cells(j, i) = "Week Start Date"
        With Cells(j, i).Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        With Cells(j, i).Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
...
...
```

Is there a more elegant way?

---

With full credit to @egan-wolf and @robinmackenzie here is the full solution I used to answer the above question.  As suggested I created a helper function and passed it the cell I want to set the borders for and the line style & weight I'd like them to be, turning 8 lines of code into a much more readable single line:

`setLeftAndRightEdges Cells(j, i), xlContinuous, xlMedium`

```
Private Sub setLeftAndRightEdges(ByVal cell As Range, ByVal lineStyle As Long, ByVal weight As Long)
      Dim edges(1) As Variant
      Dim edge As Variant

      edges(0) = xlEdgeLeft
      edges(1) = xlEdgeRight

      For Each edge In edges
            cell.Borders(edge).LineStyle = lineStyle
            cell.Borders(edge).weight = weight
      Next edge
End Sub
```

Comment: you can set borders to all 4 : left, right, top and down together

Comment: Just want left and right, not all four

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I would call it more elegant way, but this is the option to not duplicate code

```
Dim edges(1) As Variant
edges(0) = xlEdgeLeft
edges(1) = xlEdgeRight
For Each edge In edges
    ActiveCell.Borders(edge).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Next edge
```

Comment: Let me give that a try, see how much it tidy's things up.  Thanks!

Comment: You could extend that into a nice helper function to set any array of different border edges... so +1

Comment: @RobinMackenzie  Very elegant - turned 8 lines of identical code used in about 30 different places into one line easy-to-read line.  Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
With Cells(j, i)
     .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
     .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With
```

Using this you don't need an additional `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly hacky way to do it as a one-liner where `rng` is a `Range` object we have already defined:

`rng.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 3).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous`

The trick is that you want to get a range that includes the left-hand and right-hand cells to the target range and then for that group of cells, set the inside vertical border. This has the effect of setting the left-hand and right-hand border of the original cell.

- `Offset(0, -1)` goes to the left-hand cell of the target cell
- `Resize(1, 3)` extends the range to 3 columns on the row of the target cell
- `Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle...` sets the format of the inner verticals of this range of 3 cells.

Sample code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    'sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'target range
    Set rng = ws.Range("B8")

    'one-liner to set left and right borders
    rng.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 3).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous

End Sub
```

Edit: as pointed out by @EganWolf this won't work for cells in column A. Or, for that matter, it won't work in the right-handmost column of the sheet.  Additional coding will be required for these 'edge' cases.

Comment: Will not work if the original cell is in column A. It also adds additional borders in cells on sides. Border is assigned to a cell, so left border of B1 is not the same as right border of A1. You can check this by moving such a cell.

Comment: Yes, it does. That's true.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin a cat, as they say.. how about:

```
Dim edge As Variant

For edge = xlEdgeLeft To xlEdgeRight Step xlEdgeRight - xlEdgeLeft
    Cells(j, i).Borders(edge).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Next
```