# applying a border to a single cell with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm iterating over a sheet and printing cells one at a time, and to build a larder nice formatting I need to dynamically add things such as borders.

I am familiar with Range.Borders, but is it possible to, for example, add a Dashed border to the left edge of a cell using VBA?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you researched / tried so far? What's not working?

Comment: `ActiveCell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlDash`.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41801869/setting-left-and-right-cell-borders-at-the-same-time-in-vba and change the `xlContinuous` to `xldash`

Comment: Whatever formatting you want to do, record a macro while doing it, and then inspect the resulting code.  It may have a lot of unneeded lines in it, but it will give you the basic idea.

Comment: @TimWilliams this is an incredibly helpful utility, that I had no idea existed. Thanks!

Comment: @TimWilliams this seems like a calling to make a Q&A post where you ask something like "How do I write a macro in VBA" and cover the macro recorder, where to put code, etc... But i'm not articulate enough to do that well

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 - there are plenty of articles to be had via Google which talk about this.  Might have been a topic for the "Documentation" area but that's no longer a thing...  https://stackoverflow.com/documentation

Comment: Just remember that recording a macro will give you a ton of unnecessary code.Just setting a cell border to the default "Top" will produce 12 lines of code to do something that takes 2 lines.  While using the macro recorder can give you very valuable information (I use it all the time), you have to be aware that it's going to give you a lot of extra code that you don't need and/or it will produce code that can be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @TimWilliams wow that was an interesting rabbit hole, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using example

```
 ActiveCell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

You can replace xlContinuous with the xlLineStyle enumerations

Here is a list from [Microsoft Docs XlLineStyle Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff821622%28v%3Doffice.14%29)

**Name = enumeration Value** Description:

**xlContinuous = 1**  Continuous line.

**xlDash = -4115** Dashed line.

**xlDashDot = 4** Alternating dashes and dots.

**xlDashDotDot = 5** Dash followed by two dots.

**xlDot = -4118** Dotted line.

**xlDouble = -4119** Double line.

**xlLineStyleNone = -4142** No line.

**xlSlantDashDot = 13** Slanted dashes.